# I have a form I need to move the mouse over to change the color

Tags: jquery, css

Excuse me ,I have no job in this section.Here is a table. I need to change the color of the previous table

```js
$(".tab").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  $(this).prev().css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
  $(this).prev().css("background-color", "#ffffff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tab">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, you just need to use cdn top of your table. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> (I am removing my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want give unique at each cell then you will check this:-

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
    .upperCell:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .lowerCell:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<body>
<table width="300" border="1">

  <tr>

    <td class="upperCell">one</td>

    <td class="upperCell">two</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tab">

    <td class="lowerCell">one</td>

    <td class="lowerCell">two</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to show same color on each row then you will check this:--

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
    .upperCell:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .lowerCell:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<body>
<table width="300" border="1">

  <tr class="upperCell">

    <td>one</td>

    <td>two</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tab lowerCell">

    <td >one</td>

    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```